# docker-machine create --driver generic kills ssh on google compute engine

Tags: ssh, docker, certificate, google-compute-engine

Hi I am still learning docker's wonderful magical world. I use docker on linux with docker-machine I already added 2 already existing Linux servers with the `docker-machine create` and successfully run  my containers on them. Now I try to do the same with an already existing google compute engine based machine which has Linux too. I use the command:

`docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address ipaddress --generic- ssh-key path_To_Key --generic-ssh-user user_Name machine_Name`

And I get an error:

> Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or
>   regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for
>   host "X.X.X.X:2376": dial tcp X.X.X.X:2376: i/o timeout You can
>   attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs
>   [name]'.

Then the docker-machine does not know it's ip But I seems to give it a command trought `docker-machine ssh`
Altough I am not able to log in with ssh anywhere else and I must stop/remove the created machine and restart it.
Anyone has a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [generic driver's page](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/) at docker docs, try to edit `--generic-ip-address=ip_address` with equal sign.